# TypeScript with filter method - it cannot correctly infer the results of Array.isArray

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a question regarding how filter works in TS:
I have an object of type `Foo`

```
type Foo = {
  foo: number[];
  bar: number[];
  lol: string;
};

const obj: Foo = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3],
  bar: [4, 5],
  lol: "lol"
};
```

and I need to filter out the non-array values and extract the numbers

```
const re = Object.values(obj)
 .filter((val) => Array.isArray(val))
 .flatMap((num) => num);

console.log(re); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Here is the live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-mclaren-x59u8?file=/src/index.ts
However TS thinks after `.filter((val) => Array.isArray(val))` `num` could still be string, i.e. it could be `lol`. it seems like it didn't know how `.filter` works.

Even without `flatMap`, if we check to see the type of `re` you get `const re: (string | number[])[]` meaning `re` could still be a string, which is not true here since we filter it out based on `Array.isArray`.

Comment: Here's your code without the flatMap: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-volhard-s5ku9?file=/src/index.ts shows first two entries of the array created from `Object.values(obj)`.  Isn't that expected?

Comment: @danronmoon hey thanks for the reply. No it is still not expected.  If you check to see the type of `re` you get `const re: (string | number[])[]` meaning `re` could still be a string, which is not true here since we filter it out based on `Array.isArray`

Answer (score 1):

`Array.filter` returns the same array type it was called on.

But you can force it to change type by making the filter function a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), which lets the compiler know what returning `true` here really means.

```
const re = Object.values(obj)
  .filter((val): val is number[] => Array.isArray(val))
  .flatMap((num) => num); // now this works

console.log(re); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Does this enforce checks for when obj contains a field of `string[]` type?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But you could also easily do `.filter((val): val is string => typeof val === 'string')` to filter down to strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

TS isn't smart enough to know that "Oh you are filtering only for arrays and the types on `Foo` that are arrays are all `number[]` therefore output of the filter would only be `number[]`".

There are ways to trick the compiler into "knowing" that `num` is a number. But it involves *you* also knowing this fact and telling it to the compiler. Also remember, TS is only helpful at transpile time. The running code will not fail in the case that `Foo` contains some other array of type `string[]`.

So I don't know if this helps to answer your question at all but in your example I'd instead do something explicit like:

```
type Foo = {
  foo: number[];
  bar: number[];
  lol: string;
};

const obj: Foo = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3],
  bar: [4, 5],
  lol: "lol"
};

const re = obj.foo.concat(obj.bar);

console.log(re); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This way compile knows `re` is `number[]` and so will you.

If you need to loop through `Foo` then a `for of` will preserve the type.

```
const re2: number[] = [];
for (const item of Object.values(obj)) {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    re2.push(...item); // Knows it is number[]
  }
}
console.log(re2); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```